# can gradle handle infinite subproject depth?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a bunch of applications in my workspace placed like this :

```
Workspace
├── MyApp1
|   ├── app
|   |   └── build.gradle
|   ├── build.gradle
|   └── settings.gradle
└── MyApp2
    ├── app
    |   └── build.gradle
    ├── build.gradle
    └── settings.gradle
```

If I place a `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` files on my Workspace directory.

In the Workspace scope :

- Can I be able to include `:MyApp2:app` in the `settings.gradle` and will it be considered as part of `build.gradle` submodules ?
- if I include `:MyApp2` will I be able to to something like this in the `build.gradle` file :

  ```
  project(":MyApp2") {
      project(":app") {
          //doSomeStuff
      }
  }
  ```

My wish is to create automated task to publish libs / compiling apks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the infinite thing but - yes it can support multiple layers, in your settings you:

```
include 'MyApp1:app:foo:bar'
```

the colon `:` separates the project names.

then you invoke it with `:MyApp1:app:foo:bar:build` e.g. to get build task on `bar` subproject.

then only thing is - I would have 1 global `settings.gradle` in your root project.

It might be like this.

```
Workspace
├── MyApp1
|   ├── app
|   |   └── build.gradle
|   └── build.gradle
|   
├─── MyApp2
|    ├── app
|    |   └── build.gradle
|    └── build.gradle
|
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

Comment: Unless you disable it, Gradle will search for `settings.gradle` files in parent directories, so you can build each multi-project on its own or as a part of another multi-project. But, you are right that for each build only one `settings.gradle` file be interpret.